# How should I bind my form to an AJAX call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi below is my html and javascrpt which is having two text boxes and one submit button and I am getting the form values and storing the values in variable and appending to a url. Now my requirement is to execute the Url but my below code is opening the url, is there any way to execute the url without opening it.

```
<HTML>
 <HEAD>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 function validate()
 {
 var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
 var value = document.getElementById("value").value;
 var url ="http://example.net.net/ftp/Ftp? name="+ name+"&value="+value;
 window.open(url);
  }
 </script>
 </HEAD>
 <BODY>
 <form name="Form1" method="post" action="" onsubmit="return validate();">
   <input type="text" size="15" id="name" value=""/>
   <input type="text" size="15" id="value" value=""/>
   <input type ="submit" value ="submit" >
</form>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

I have tried  `window.location =url`; also bt not able to execute it, please suggest me.
Thanks

Comment: "execute url from browser without executing the url" - that's very Zen, but a contradiction in terms. What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: What do you mean by "execute URL"? Send a request?

Comment: What you are trying to accomplish? If you want to store the response of the http call, you have to use AJAX. Beware that your url does not appear to be correct. Check if it is 
"http://example.net/ftp/Ftp?name="

Comment: I mentioned that "execute the url form browser without opening it" not "execute url from browser without executing the url".It should hit that URL internally not to open the Url in next browser or current browser.Is there any way let me know

Comment: Reread your title, you mistyped it. Also, please use correct terms. It's very hard to understand what exactly you're after. I assume you're looking for an AJAX solution which is why I've updated the title of your question accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you want to do a GET request.

I would use AJAX for this:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: '/my/url',
  success: function(jqXhr) {
    console.log(jqXhr.responseText);
  },
  error: function() {

  }
})
```

If you're not comfortable with JQuery you could do this (IE8+):

```
request = new XMLHttpRequest
request.open('GET', '/my/url', true)
request.send()

request.onload = function() {
  console.log(this.response);
}

request.onerror = function() {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to open a url in new window right? 
Try window.open

```
window.open(url,'_blank');
```